# ViewModel contains collection of another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In all tutorial about MVVM I read that `View` should not know about `Model`, hence `ViewModel` layer is introduced.

If so in situation like: we have `Shelf` which contains `Pack`:

```
namespace Storage.Model
{
    class Pack
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="Storage.View.Shelf" ... >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Capability}"/>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Packs}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
// DataContext for Shelf 
namespace Storage.ViewModel
{
    public class ShelfViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Capability { get; set; }
        // It's okay that ViewModel contains collection of another ViewModel?
        public ObservableCollection<PackViewModel> Packs { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

```
// DataContext for Pack
namespace Storage.ViewModel
{
    class PackViewModel
    {
        private Pack pack;
        public string Name 
        {
           get{ return pack.Name; }
           set{ ... }
        }

        public PackViewModel(int id)
        {
            // How to populate reference to Pack instance?
            pack = (new PackRepository()).getById(id) 
        }
    }
}
```

Like I mention in code comment above, it okey that one ViewModel create instances of another ViewModel? I can image case where we have `Storage`  with collection of `Shelf`, hence we end up with cascading reference to ModelView: `StoreViewModel` contains `ObservableCollection<ShelfViewModel>` which cotains collection of `ObservableCollection<PackViewModel>`.

Another problem with arise with that solution is that how to populate newly introduced `PackViewModel` with reference to `Pack` class? We must somehow pass unique identifier to `PackViewModel` instance.

I don't want hide that this question is related to my other question [Shoud view layer know about model classes (entities)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141143/shoud-view-layer-know-about-model-classes-entities)

Comment: Why are you making your life complicated without a reason? No one ever said that a view model should not use a class from the model layer. Your PackViewModel is redundant. It is absolutely ok to have a `ObservableCollection<Pack>`.

Comment: Sorry for asking obvious things. I'm just learning MVVM and, try understanding how architecture problems are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like I mention in code comment above, it okey that one ViewModel create instances of another ViewModel?

Yes. In this case `PackViewModel` is just a wrapper around `Pack`. You typically use such a wrapper when you don't want to expose or bind to the model type directly or when the model type doesn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for example.

This is perfectly fine. You will indeed end up with more classes, but each class has its own responsibility. You could for example extend the wrapper class with properties that are specific to the UI, i.e. properties that are obly there for the view to bind to.

> Another problem with arise with that solution is that how to populate newly introduced PackViewModel with reference to `Pack` class? We must somehow pass unique identifier to `PackViewModel` instance

You could just inject the wrapper class with the wrapped object when you create it:

```
class PackViewModel
{
    private readonly Pack _pack;
    public PackViewModel(Pack pack)
    {
        _pack = pack;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _pack.Name; }
    }
}
```

Given a collection of `Pack` objects that you may have received from some kind of repository or service, you could then easily create wrapper objects, e.g.:

```
var repo = PackRepository();
var packs = repo.GetPacks();
var wrapperObjects = packs.Select(pack => new PackViewModel(pack));
```

Comment: I know I can inject `Pack` object to `PackViewModel`. The problem is how to do it, because only`Shelf ViewModel` is aware of intended collections, `PackViewModel` must be informed. So I need communicate between them. I alredy found solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029801/how-should-i-communicate-between-viewmodels.

Comment: To sum up my MVVM dilemma. MVVM (C#+WPF) didn't provide native solution for this kind of relation, we have to solve it by ourselves, hence frameworks MVVM Light, Calibre and theirs: ViewModelLocator, Messenger.Default etc...

Comment: Anyway thanks for your time. Especially that my question is already downvoted.