# WPF datagrid not updating when using Entity Framework Core Models

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, entity-framework-core

I have a WPF window to display details of a training class, and a list of attendees in a datagrid.

I am using Entity Framework Core and my training class model looks like this

```
public partial class TrainingClass
{
    public TrainingClass()
    {
        TrainingAttendees = new HashSet<TrainingAttendee>();
    }

    public int ClassId { get; set; } // PK
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TrainingAttendee> TrainingAttendees { get; set; }
}
```

In my `TrainingClassDetailsViewModel` I have a button that opens a dialog window where the user enters in the attendee details and clicks a Save button

```
public void AddAttendee(object parameter)
{
    TrainingAttendee attendee = new TrainingAttendee()

    TrainingAttendeeViewModel vm = new TrainingAttendeeViewModel(attendee);
    _windowService.ShowDialog<TrainingAttendeeEditor>(vm);

    if (vm.SaveClicked)
    {
        _trainingClass.TrainingAttendees.Add(attendee);
    }
}
```

This adds the new attendee so EF Core can update the database when `SaveChanges` is called, but this does not update the datagrid.

I'm aware I need to use `ObservableCollection` which uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  If I implement the following and use `Attendees.Add(attendee);` instead, this will update the datagrid, but will not update the database.

```
private ObservableCollection<TrainingAttendee> _attendees;
public ObservableCollection<TrainingAttendee> Attendees
{
    get => _attendees;
    set
    {
        if (_attendees != value)
        {
            _attendees = value;
            ApplyPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}

...

_attendees = new ObservableCollection<TrainingAttendee>(_trainingClass.TrainingAttendees);
```

The only working method I can get is to do both `_trainingClass.TrainingAttendees.Add(attendee);` and `Attendees.Add(attendee);`.  But I find this odd by managing 2 lists.  And I need my own `ApplyPropertyChanged` to be called instead.

How would I best implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ObservableCollection<T>` as a backing store for your collection navigation properties (in place of the current `HashSet<T>`). Or even better, the EF Core provided [`ObservableHashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.observablehashset-1?view=efcore-5.0) class. e.g.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking; // <-- required

public partial class TrainingClass
{
    public TrainingClass()
    {
        TrainingAttendees = new ObservableHashSet<TrainingAttendee>(); // <--
    }

    //...

    public virtual ICollection<TrainingAttendee> TrainingAttendees { get; set; }
}
```

For more info, see [Notification entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#notification-entities) section and the whole [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/) topic in the official EF Core documentation.

Also, if you are using EF Core 5.0 or later, you can utilize EF Core [Change-tracking proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#change-tracking-proxies) which basically implement all `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` functionality for you. But you need to make *all* your properties *virtual* and also have access to `DbContext` and use [`CreateProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.proxiesextensions.createproxy?view=efcore-5.0) extension method instead of `new` for creating new entity instances.

Comment: Yet again you made me aware of interesting developments in the EF core department!

Comment: Thank you.  Adding items seems to work well.  But editing them does not update the datagrid, and an exception is thrown when trying to remove: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection Remove event must specify item position.'`

Comment: @smally Since all this is from MS (EF Core), if something doesn't work. either there is a bug in the EFC version used or the way you use it. Make sure to read the whole documentation from the provided links and the end of the answer. For instance, of course edit won't reflect in the view if the entity class does not implement the `INPC` interfaces. You need to implement that yourself or use EF Core change tracking proxies as mentioned. etc. For the `Remove`, I'm not sure, - EFC had/has a lot of bugs, but can't believe they've missed such elementary case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example why you should not bind directly to auto-generated (EF) model classes.

You should bind to view models or wrapper classes and convert/map between your entity objects and these.

In your `AddAttendee` method you wold then add the entity to the context like you are currently doing but also add a view model/wrapper to a data-bound `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
if (vm.SaveClicked)
{
     //1. add to EF context
    _trainingClass.TrainingAttendees.Add(attendee);
     //2. Add to source data-bound collection
    vm.SourceCollection.Add(new Wrapper(attendee));
}
```

You'll find an example of a view model class that "wraps" a model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149162/7252182).